# Box shadow not working for 2 adjacent divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with using box-shadow. Below is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100" style="background-color : #F0F0F0;">
    <div id="row1" class="row" style="box-shadow : 0 5px 10px 0 black; height: 100px;">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            LOGO
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9" style="background-color: aqua">
            HEADER
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="row2" class="row" style="height: 300px;">
        <div id="sectiona" class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: aqua;">
            Section A
        </div>
        <div id="sectionb" class="col-lg-9">
            Section B
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The box-shadow is not working for the id="sectiona" div? I tried using z-index but still not working. Any solution to this? I'm using bootstrap 4.

Comment: I wanted it to look like this https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-n2mqvU2RocA/Wm_7iKQqClI/AAAAAAAABY0/0EiEanKp1SIACMnrnwOvNXGBiKUppxHUQCL0BGAYYCw/h443/2018-01-29.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` property requires that the element's `position` is set.

```
<div id="row1" class="row" style="position: relative; z-index: 1; box-shadow : 0 5px 10px 0 black; height: 100px;">
```

Comment: I want the logo div to still have shadow below.

Comment: They will both have a shadow if both of them has the `box-shadow` property?

Comment: I wanted it to look like this https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-n2mqvU2RocA/Wm_7iKQqClI/AAAAAAAABY0/0EiEanKp1SIACMnrnwOvNXGBiKUppxHUQCL0BGAYYCw/h443/2018-01-29.png

Comment: Ah okay very helpful. Will update answer to match in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the box-shadow style to the div with id="row2".  That will give you a box-shadow in that section.